# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function with fullcalendar-rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

i'm trying to add [fullcalendar-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails) to my project, but it's not working and i can't figure out what's the problem.

It's added to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
```

Then into application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require moment
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require fullcalendar
//= require_tree .
```

And application.css (not .css.scss):

```
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require fullcalendar
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

This is the .js i'm using to load the calendar:

```
$( document).ready( function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' },
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        eventLimit: true,
        events: source
    });
})
```

But it just doesn't work and the browsers console shows this Error:

```
Failed to get text for stylesheet 31: No style sheet with given id found
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -> pointing at: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
```

So it basically doesn't know about fullCalendar.

The thing is everything works just fine if i use [vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine](https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine), but the gem is much more limited and doesn't include functions like locale and slotDuration. So i'd like to replace it with fullcalendar-rails.

Anyway, i'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, since it's kind of hard to tell without looking at your project, but did you add it to your layout?

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "the-stylesheet", :media => "all" %>
```

Or if you are relying on rail asset pipeline, make sure you have asset precompilation set or you run the rake command to do the compilation.

Comment: Sorry @gchaturvedi, you mean adding "fullcalendar.css" to the layout?

Comment: Yeah, it can't find a stylesheet, so maybe it's missing and needs to be linked to where you are adding your JS code.  Also, are you compiling your assets properly?  It also doesn't seem like the selector can find $('#calendar') since it's returning as undefined.

Comment: i'm compiling assets manually (rake assets:precompile) and it doesnt make a difference. Get your point with the stylesheets but its all in the same gem. Shouldnt it load it by default?

Comment: Do you have the following lines in your application.html.erb?   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
Then it technically should with rails asset pipeline if you are running the rake command above.

Comment: I just tried setting it up on a brand new rails project myself and was able to get it working.  Try a rake assets:clean and manually delete your "tmp" folder.  Then a rake assets:precompile.  Another issue could be some other stylesheets you have are clobbering fullCalendar's styles.

Comment: there's something on my assets pipeline i cant figure out. Thanks @cghatuverdi. I'll try to figure this out.